# connection issue in connecting Squirrel SQL to DB2 locally

Tags: db2, db2-luw, squirrel-sql

I installed DB2 on my laptop and created an instance called 'TEST1' and well as two databases 'DB1' and 'DB_TEST1' in that instance.

[image]

I'm trying to connect squirrel sql client to DB2. I'm using DB1 or DB_TEST1 as the database name but I'm getting the following error message

```
test connection 1: [jcc][4038][12241][4.23.42] T2LUW exception: SQL1031N    The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system.    SQLSTATE=58031
ERRORCODE=-1031, SQLSTATE=58031
class com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][4038][12241][4.23.42] T2LUW  exception: SQL1031N  The database directory cannot be found on the indicated   file system.  SQLSTATE=58031
ERRORCODE=-1031, SQLSTATE=58031
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Have you configured the Db2-instance for remote access, and ensured that the Windows-firewall allows traffic on that port? jdbc does not use the local catalog.

Comment: I just installed db2 and that's it. What else I need to do? I'm using it locally, do I need to configure db2_instance for remote access?

Comment: Also, check if you can connect to the databases *on the command line* (in db2ntcmd.exe).

Comment: I can issue the command 'db2 connect to db1' and it prints out database connection information, that's good enough right?

Comment: Follow the instructions at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0004714.html  , and if you already did that, then show your connection string from squirrel-sql

Comment: I followed the instruction but I'm still getting the same error. Where can I find the connction string from squirrel?

Comment: Please add more details to the question, which version of Db2 you are using? where do u installed it? where does it stores the actual database file? what are your jdbc parameters(jdbc url)?; A a wild guess, maybe you need to run/start SquirrelSQL with an administrator user(on Windows) account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you created the Db2-instance manually, you will need to do more manual steps to configure that Db2-instance. If you choose defaults during installation, the wizard creates and configures an instance for you.

You need to allocate your Db2-instance an unused port-number on which to listen for TCP connections, and bounce the instance. Typically that is port 50000 or 60000 for unencrypted connections.

Follow instructions [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/t0004727.html) and on all related and subsidiary pages.

You then need to tell Squirrel-SQL this port number on the connection-string (also known as the URL: field on the 'Add Alias' screen).  For example, this might read something like the following if using a Type-4 Db2 driver:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/sample
```

where localhost is your hostname, and you chose port 50000 on which your Db2-instance should listen for connections, and your database name is sample.

*The Db2-instance has to be running, and listening on the specified port, otherwise the connection will fail.*

Other types of Db2 drivers can use a different URL format.

Comment: It worked, but my question is what is the other option to set up an instance rather than manual option?

Comment: The db2setup java gui has the functionality to create the default Db2 instance and configure it for you. However, it's common to create your own Db2-instances and if you have enough RAM and CPU you can create two or more instances on the same hostname, each operates independently of the other. Each needs separate configuration. This is common on Linux/Unix but it also works on Windows if resources allow.